# Which image processing library should I use to create a video slideshow?

Tags: android, video, image-processing, ffmpeg, slideshow

It looks like both [FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) and the [MovieMaker library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/MovieMaker.html) in Processing will create a slideshow movie from an array of images. Which is best? Is there a better option?

I need to output a video to be uploaded to a 3rd party website so I'd like to do it on device and it needs to be a real video not just a gallery slideshow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) is a great option.  I've done it many times myself with **[time lapse photography experiments](http://geekomatic.ch/2010/03/06/1267890120000.html)**.

1. Install FFmpeg with x264 CODEC
2. Number all your slides starting at 0001.jpg
3. Run FFmpeg like below *(this is what I use for my images-->video conversions)*:

FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i %04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 -vpre main -vpre normal \
   -r 25 -an -threads 4 -b 3000k -mbd rd -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 \
   -subcmp 2 -g 300 -y out.mp4
```

You may need to tinker with the command line to get the desired output quality you are searching for.  Also, the frame rate (`-r 25`) is probably too high for you.  Either experiment with small values, or duplicate your slides programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, Can you give me any link or code that have implemented this..I dont have experience with NDK developement..and stuck in the problem and require urgent solution...thanks :)

Comment: Exactly please give me any link exactly implemented what you have said