# Error while executing build.sh in ffmpeg-android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cygwin

I downloaded ffmpeg-android from the link : http://bambuser.com/opensource

I followed the steps given in the file README available in that downloaded folder.

I tried compiling ffmpeg with both android NDK r5 and r6, but got the same error which is as below:

```
 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

 If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from SVN.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@mplayerhq.hu mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

**Cygwin Version:** 1.7.9

Please someone help me in resolving it.

Comment: You should probably add your building environment too (you said Cygwin? Which version? Which version of make, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, but on Ubuntu 64-bit.
The NDK is compiled for 32-bit, so I had to install ia32-libs.
Got it working by installing:

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

If that doesn't help, you could also try making sure that Android SDK and Java is installed.