# Compress Videos using FFMPEG and JNI

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, android-videoview

I want to create an android application which can locate a video file  (which is more than 300 mb) and compress it to lower size  mp4 file.

i already tried to do it with [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)

This tutorial is a very effective since you 're compressing a small size video  (below than 100 mb)

So i tried to implement it using JNI .

i managed to build ffmpeg using  [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

But currently what I want to do is to compress videos . I don't have very good knowledge on JNI. But i tried to understand it using following [link](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Developing_Multimedia_Applications_with_NDK.pdf)

If some one can guide me the steps to compress video after open file it using JNI that whould really great , thanks

Comment: you say that the tutorial is very effective for small size video. So is there any problem when you follow the same for large videos?

Comment: @AndroSelva yes, actually its device oriented

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you've got the String path of the input file, we can accomplish your task fairly easily. I'll assume you have an understanding of the NDK basics: How to connect a native .c file to `native` methods in a corresponding .java file (Let me know if that's part of your question). Instead I'll focus on how to use FFmpeg within the context of Android / JNI.

**High-Level Overview:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

#define LOG_TAG "FFmpegWrapper"
#define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)


void Java_com_example_yourapp_yourJavaClass_compressFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jInputPath, jstring jInputFormat, jstring jOutputPath, jstring JOutputFormat){
  // One-time FFmpeg initialization
  av_register_all();
  avformat_network_init();
  avcodec_register_all();

  const char* inputPath = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jInputPath, NULL);
  const char* outputPath = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jOutputPath, NULL);
  // format names are hints. See available options on your host machine via $ ffmpeg -formats
  const char* inputFormat = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jInputFormat, NULL);
  const char* outputFormat = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jOutputFormat, NULL);

  AVFormatContext *outputFormatContext = avFormatContextForOutputPath(outputPath, outputFormat);
  AVFormatContext *inputFormatContext = avFormatContextForInputPath(inputPath, inputFormat /* not necessary since file can be inspected */);

  copyAVFormatContext(&outputFormatContext, &inputFormatContext);
  // Modify outputFormatContext->codec parameters per your liking
  // See http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html

  int result = openFileForWriting(outputFormatContext, outputPath);
  if(result < 0){
      LOGE("openFileForWriting error: %d", result);
  }

  writeFileHeader(outputFormatContext);

  // Copy input to output frame by frame
  AVPacket *inputPacket;
  inputPacket = av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));

  int continueRecording = 1;
  int avReadResult = 0;
  int writeFrameResult = 0;
  int frameCount = 0;
  while(continueRecording == 1){
      avReadResult = av_read_frame(inputFormatContext, inputPacket);
      frameCount++;
      if(avReadResult != 0){
        if (avReadResult != AVERROR_EOF) {
            LOGE("av_read_frame error: %s", stringForAVErrorNumber(avReadResult));
        }else{
            LOGI("End of input file");
        }
        continueRecording = 0;
      }

      AVStream *outStream = outputFormatContext->streams[inputPacket->stream_index];
      writeFrameResult = av_interleaved_write_frame(outputFormatContext, inputPacket);
      if(writeFrameResult < 0){
          LOGE("av_interleaved_write_frame error: %s", stringForAVErrorNumber(avReadResult));
      }
  }

  // Finalize the output file
  int writeTrailerResult = writeFileTrailer(outputFormatContext);
  if(writeTrailerResult < 0){
      LOGE("av_write_trailer error: %s", stringForAVErrorNumber(writeTrailerResult));
  }
  LOGI("Wrote trailer");
}
```

For the full content of all the auxillary functions (the ones in camelCase), see my full project on [Github](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/FFmpegTest/blob/365fdd214f5749400107924a91b23f1580244490/jni/FFmpegWrapper.c). Got questions? I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: i'll try it and let u know , can u send me ur mail address,

Comment: I have downloaded your sample application from GIT but it that seems it works for only android 4.4

Comment: as u said i know "How to connect a native .c file to native methods in a corresponding .java file" i want to know the native c code to compress video, i tried to execute ut Github project but it seems that it works on android 4.4

Comment: The GitHub project I linked is an experiment with [MediaCocec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) and FFmpeg, and that's where the Android 4.3 requirement comes from. The core files you want to include in your app are the `jni/` folder and `FFmpegWrapper.java`. You'll modify FFmpegWrapper.c and FFmpegWrapper.java to only expose the one function I included in my response. Also see my notes on [building FFmpeg for Android](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/FFmpeg-Android) when you need to configure the FFmpeg libraries for your needs.

Comment: i tried to excute program i recieve this error in my log-cat

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   138 could not load needed library 'libavformat-55.so' for 'libFFmpegWrapper.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libavformat-55.so' not found)

But the libavcodec-55.so is available in the lib folder

Comment: Have you also copied [Android.mk](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/FFmpegTest/blob/365fdd214f5749400107924a91b23f1580244490/jni/Android.mk)? What happens when you run `ndk-build` in your terminal from the project's jni directory?

Comment: yeah . i copied Android.mk file and ndk-build runs and it will build app the .so files . So i think thr is an issue with linking files . Also i tried to run ur sample application  . it gives same error.

Comment: Can you post the source to your application?

Comment: i have made a sample application to run ur native source . but it gives that error , which i mentioned above .  i f u send me mail address i can send you the source code'

Comment: Put it up on Github so we can share the solution with everyone here.

Comment: sure. i'll add it to github.

Comment: @dbro How can I call this function with desired parameters ? I know how to call it.. but specifically doubt about passing params.

Comment: I spend a lot of time and later could not get past the error
undefined reference to 'avformat_new_stream' 'avformat_close_input' and some more functions. I could see these functions were defined in libavformat/utils.c but when I try to import, the compiler cannot find utils.c and I am still unable to compile the code.

Comment: @dbro : Hello, " How to connect a native .c file to native methods in a corresponding .java file" is my issue, would you like to help me? I know `Java_com_example_yourapp_yourJavaClass_compressFile` means what. But I don't know how to define in Java class and MK file to load it, call this method ...

Comment: It just copies video not compresses the size.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia to compress you modify AVFormatContext *outputFormatContext after it's initialized with `copyAVFormatContext`. See the comment in the code I embedded for a helpful link to the FFmpeg docs.

Comment: I think we need to know how to compress the video.Which method can do it?

Comment: in this method "inputformat" and "outputformat" which value passed from java class ?