# How to Play AC3 on Android?

Tags: java, android, media, decode

Is there any way to play AC3 on Android? I don't want to use a 3rd party application. I've heard about Ffmpeg but could someone explain me how to use it for decoding AC3? I have already got ffmpeg libraries like libavcodec.so etc. but don't know how to use them. On the other hand, I may add extractor and decoder for AC3 on libstagefright but I really need help for it.

Comment: Maybe this question might be at value to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android