# Audio Android.Mixing a song and a voice recorded!

Tags: android, audio

I am developing a karaoke app and i have been dealing with audio from android.I want an opinion on how can i save a single song from a voice recorded and another song playing in the background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try **FFMPEG Library for Android**, consider using [android wrapper](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java). There are several SO answers of help

[Audio song mixer in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228196/audio-song-mixer-in-android-programatically)

[How to overlay two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg)

[FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android?lq=1)

You may want to check [amerge](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) and [amix](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) ffmpeg filters based on your needs

**[SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)** is a good option if requirements can be met just by playing two audio streams together.

> SoundPool can also manage the number of audio streams being rendered
>   at once. When the SoundPool object is constructed, the maxStreams
>   parameter sets the maximum number of streams that can be played at a
>   time from this single SoundPool.

Also note [**Android - Lollipop**](http://www.android.com/versions/lollipop-5-0/) version now supports [**multi-channel audio stream mixing**](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/implement.html)

> Multi-channel audio stream mixing means professional audio
>   applications can now mix up to eight channels including 5.1 and 7.1
>   channels.
>
> **Multi-channel support**
>
> If your hardware and driver supports multichannel audio via HDMI, you
>   can output the audio stream directly to the audio hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an "On device" way to combine two audio files into one. The best you can do is play both at the same time from what I've read.

See [Sound Pool Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)