# Bitmap rendering in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I need help regarding rendering of Bitmaps and displaying them as a video in Android. Does someone know how to do it?

I am also attaching the code with this for your understanding..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Read extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File file = new File("C:/Users/amrit.pati/Desktop/downloads/H324mVideoEncInput.yuv");

       try {

            onPreviewFrame(getBytesFromFile(file));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        long length = file.length();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {

        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        int offset = 0;

        int numRead = 0;

        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {

            offset += numRead;
        }

        if (offset < bytes.length) {

            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        is.close();

        return bytes;
    }


    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data) {

          int width = 480;

          int height = 360;

          final int[] rgb = decodeYUV420SP(data, width, height);

          Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    }

    public int[] decodeYUV420SP( byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {   

        final int frameSize = width * height;   

        int rgb[]=new int[width*height];

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {  

            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {

                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;

                if (y < 0) y = 0;

                if ((i & 1) == 0) {

                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;

                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;   
                }   

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;

                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);

                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);

                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);   

                if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;

                if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;

                if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;   

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);   


            }

        }

        return rgb;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amrit. Please be more specific. What do you mean by rendering bitmaps as a video?

Comment: I mean to say, dat I have a native code which supplies me Video frames in form of byte arrays[] , I get these in Java layer convert them into rgb frames from YUV and den those RGB into Bitmaps, Now i need to display these as Bitmaps continuously as the same video as Byte Array[].

Comment: Ok, I see now! I'm sorry, I can't tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) question about using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) with android.