# How to play MP4 videos on Android 1.5?

Tags: android, mp4

Ineed to play a short MP4 video on my android app I'm searching info about how to load mp4 videos but i can't find the way to do it on Android 1.5. My app sould be compatible from Android 1.5 to 4.0

I tryed with a lot of tutorials from google, from stackoverflow, from android developers groups, etc.., but i can't make working any of them. For example, now i'm trying with the VideoViewDemo from android developers: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html   But i can't make working the code, i dont know what is the problem, i just cant play mp4 videos with that code. And also i can't with all the code examples i find on internet.

I have a video on my ASSETS folder, and i just need to play the video, only this. I can not believe that doesn't exists a simple and quick way to do it.

**If someone can give me a tutorial or a working example of playing mp4 videos on android i will apreciate it a lot.**

Thanks

Comment: I think but I am not sure that MP4 is not supported in 1.5

Comment: @ if you want to play mp4 in android 1.5 then you have to look to use http://ffmpeg.org/index.html decoding from that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this link http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

```
 path = "/mnt/sdcard/file.mp4";
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

@AndroidUser99 you need to use following thing to work mp4 and other in android.

1:[Rockpler free coder may use for android](http://rockplayer.freecoder.org/index_en.html)

2:[android ffmpeg](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264)

3:[some SO Question for ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

you can also download FFmpeg library used before 1.7.0 from this link and use it in your project [click here](http://rockplayer.freecoder.org/tech_en.html)

Hope you will get idea to play mp4 on android 1.5.