# Strange issue in Combining Audio Files and playing in different API versions

Tags: android, audio, version, media

All , I am using **Media Recorder for Recording Audio**.

Case 1: If i use **Android Version 2.2 installed devices**, my recorded audio combined and playing well.

Case 2: If i use it in **Android 1.6 installed devices**, i am not able to play the combined audio file.

It is playing only the very first recorded audio and **next recorded audio files keep empty no sound**.

Also i am **not getting** any **error in Logcat**.

I used following code for recording audio :

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(main_record_file);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.prepare();
    mRecorder.start();
```

Also i tried for  `mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);`

Code for combining Audio file :

```
    public void createCombineRecFile(){
    combined_file_stored_path=getFilename_combined_raw(); // File path in String to store recorded audio
    byte fileContent[]=null;
    FileInputStream ins;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try{
        fos = new FileOutputStream(combined_file_stored_path,true);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<audNames.size();i++){
        try{
            File f=new File(audNames.get(i));
            Log.v("Record Message", "File Length=========>>>"+f.length());
            fileContent = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            ins=new FileInputStream(audNames.get(i));
            int r=ins.read(fileContent);// Reads the file content as byte from the list.
            Log.v("Record Message", "Number Of Bytes Readed=====>>>"+r);
            fos.write(fileContent);//Write the byte into the combine file.

            Log.v("Record Message", "File======="+i+"is Appended");

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try{
        fos.close();
        Log.v("Record Message", "===== Combine File Closed =====");
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Let me know any details need.Thanks.

Comment: From what you describe the problem is in the combination of format and "way of combining audio files"... any reason for using RAW_AMR/AMR_NB ? the way you combine audio files should work better if you use MPEG_4 instead...

Comment: I tried with both 3gp and RAW_AMR/AMR_NB format,but no luck. Format not at all a matter, i need to record audio and just combine it.and play in all devices..That's it

Comment: Hi, i am recording audio file using media recorder. i have to combine two MP4 file i do not know how to do that? please help me? i am using recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every audio file has its own header (includes information about length/samples etc.) - by combining the files the way you do the resulting file has multiple headers, one per source file (depending on the exact format with file offsets etc.).
Thus the resulting file is NOT correct in terms of file format spec.

The newer Android version are more permissive and work/play with "multiple headers" present... the older versions do not...

To create a correctly combined audio file you must conform to the spec which among other things means creating one new header which describes all included audio...

Use for the the combination of audio files a different approach - for example via ffmpeg (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820282/847363) for how to make ffmpeg for android).

Comment: @Venky not on android but yes... since from what I gather the above is a way to make ffmpeg work on android I would definitely give it a try...

Comment: My question is how to resolve my problem , not an alternate Solution for Combining Audio Files.

Comment: @Venky the problem you face comes from the way you combine the audio files... so that part needs to change to make it work IMO...

Comment: @Venky added an explanation...HTH

Comment: I need to check all these things newly,since i am not having any idea about ffmpeg. It will be helpful for me for further reference link ans Sample to go ahead with ffmpeg.

Comment: @Venky an alternative would be to use `javax.sound.sampled` package for combining but this has been removed in newer Android SDKs :-(

Answer (score 1):

Foreword: Haven't tested this, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Provided the headers ARE the cause of this problem, you can solve it really easily. Using the code you've given, the encoding is AMR-NB. According to [this document](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AMR_format) the AMR header is simply the first 6 bytes, which are 0x23, 0x21, 0x41, 0x4D, 0x52, 0x0A. If the headers in subsequent files are causing the issue, simply omit those bytes from subsequent files e.g.

```
write all bytes of first file
write from byte[6] -> byte[end] of subsequent files
```

Let me know how it goes.

EDIT: At request, change the try block to:

```
try{
        File f=new File(audNames.get(i));
        Log.v("Record Message", "File Length=========>>>"+f.length());
        fileContent = new byte[(int)f.length()];

        ///////////////new bit////////

        //same as you had, this opens a byte stream to the file
        ins=new FileInputStream(audNames.get(i));
        //reads fileContent.length bytes
        ins.read(fileContent);
        //now fileContent contains the entire audio file - in bytes.
        if(i>0){
            //we are not writing the first audio recording, but subsequent ones
            //so we don't want the header included in the write

            //copy the entire file, but not the first 6 bytes
            byte[] headerlessFileContent = new byte[fileContent.length()-6];
            for(int j=6; j<fileContent.length();j++){
                headerlessFileContent[j-6] = fileContent[j];
            }
            fileContent = headerlessFileContent;
        }
        ////////////////////////////

        Log.v("Record Message", "Number Of Bytes Readed=====>>>"+r);
        fos.write(fileContent);//Write the byte into the combine file.

        Log.v("Record Message", "File======="+i+"is Appended");

    }
```

Comment: 2.2+ devices will be able to just skip over multiple headers (or should). This shouldn't affect those devices.

Comment: edited post - not sure if this method will work but I see no logical reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: I am getting The method copyOfRange(int, int) is undefined for the type Arrays

Comment: Oh that's because you dont have Java 6, you can just copy it manually then

Comment: Forgot to set headerlessFileContent size to length-6, edited that in.

Comment: You shouldn't get the same error - you shouldn't have Arrays.copyOfRange anywhere in your code.