# how to remove black screen when switching activity( is not working) - on android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

in my app, i am switching one activity to another activity (Main.java to Feature_Screen.java). In the Feature_Screen(second activity) i am going to download large no of data and image to set in a grid view. so that i use Async Task for download it. although i use async task in second activity i get black screen while switching Main.java to Feature.java. i search in google but all the answers says use Async Task.

example coding:

```
public class Main extends TabActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabbar);
    .................
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Featured_Screen1.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.top_book_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    ...........
}
}
```

In Feature_Screen1.java(Second.java):

```
public class Feature_Screen1 extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feature);
    .................
      new Content_load().execute();
    ...........
}

 class Content_load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
   {
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInPage.this);

protected void onPreExecute() { 
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      ..........
  return null;
   }
  } 

}
```

my problem is how to avoid black screen while switching between activities? please help me.

Comment: Do you see the "Please wait" dialog at all?

Comment: yes but before getting "Please Wait" i get black screen after few seconds i get please wait....

Comment: It looks like something hanging UI thread before AsyncTask get started. Post the dots code before new Content_load().execute(); in your Feature_Screen1.onCreate() may help other people find your problem.

Comment: @murali_ma hi buddy.. Have you got the answer for your question.. because the same problem i am facing now... please if you got the answer post it.. it will be really helpul.. thanks

Comment: @user1216003 hi buddy, No i do not get the answer for this question.my guess also is UI is hanging in the activity.

Comment: @murali_ma its alright.. anyway thanks for your reply.. If i found the answer i will let you know thanks...

Comment: @user1216003, please let me know the answer if you found. thanks

Comment: Finally i found the answer, please see it below

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer for black screen problem..

Use AsyncTask like below, this worked for me, if you face any problems let me know

```
public class SyncroniseRecords extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {  
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    } 
    @Override 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
     }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    { 
           dialog.cancel();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

This will launch the Activity without any Black Screen. Using `onPreExecute` you can display the Progressbar.Once the process gets completed you can cancel it in `OnPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your kind reply. i have one problem in android that is i need to convert wav file to mp3. do you know how to do it? please help me. i want to touch with you ever.

Comment: Have you solved that problem..For wav to mp3 please[Check this Link](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android).It may help you..