# Convert pcm data to low size audio type - Java/Android

Tags: java, android, mp3, pcm, amr

In my android app ,I need to convert raw pcm data (wav file) to different music type because the pcm file is 40mb for 4-5 min.

Does anyone can recommend to what type i need to convert? mp3? amr? aac?

Also, how can I convert? From what I read, there is no library in java for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer different parts of your questions 
 **Recommended compression format for audio**  
MP3 or AAC compression format is suited for music content and AMR is better suited for speech content.

**Method of conversion (compression)**  
Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and below does not expose media encoders as a JAVA API. So in these Android versions, best option is to use external compression library like FFMPEG or FAAC through JNI API.

More details about using FFMPEG is at [FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

In Android 4.1 version (Jelly Bean version), Media encoder APIs have been exposed as a java API and can be used from Java application.