# calling ffmpeg from java on android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

Currently I have a java application that calls ffmpeg process with parameters.
This works fine under Windows because I just run another process.
I want to call the same method in ffmpeg api under android os.

What should I do in order to have minimal change in code and transform the same thing to android?

How can I call, using java, a specific method in ffmpeg api under the android os.

thank you!

Comment: Do you really mean API or the command line interface (so calling the *.exe on Windows, etc.) ?

Comment: @TheSHEEEP 
Currently I am calling command line interface.

Comment: You will need to use JNI and call an NDK wrapper of ffmpeg. Check out this SO Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android

Comment: @Lior: please use the search function, and look at the related questions. This has been asked & answered numerous times.

Comment: @Mat I have searched for related questions and I couldn't find any answer that relates specific to Java. I am not familier with C/C++, so wrapping ffmpeg using NDK is my least favorite solution.