# Video recording format .mkv for android

Tags: java, android, video

I am able to record video in mp4 and 3gp formats in android.But how can I record and save video in .mkv format.Is it possible to do this in android.Is android supports .mkv format.Please provide solution.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You can check all the supported formats of android in Audio,Video and Images.
[Supported Media Formats in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: I've already checked it.It tells that android supports .mkv format.But how can I record.I tried a lot.But didn't get any solution from google.

Comment: @revathi use can use this link for recording tutorial https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=9ACF6480A5FD9DDFEDE7ED6CD35C97EF?recipeId=1375

Comment: Thank you. It's useful. I've done recording with .3gp and .mp4 formats.But I want some more formats.

Comment: I think .mkv is not a container format.It's container format is Matroska. .mkv is file extension.

Comment: Yes mkv is the file extention used for Matroska containers. Here is an FAQ: https://www.matroska.org/technical/guides/faq/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. But mkv isn't a video format it's a container format where you can put in multiple videos and audio lines. mkv can contain many video and audio format, and if you are able to view them depends on your player/recorder.
And i think you won't record in this format instead "convert"(pack) it.
you can use ffmpeg:

"[FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android/4820282#4820282)"

"[Is there any way to port ffmpeg command to Android without root the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097008/is-there-any-way-to-port-ffmpeg-command-to-android-without-root-the-device)"

Comment: except mp4 and 3gp what are the other formats we can use to record video.