# Programmatic video transcoding

Tags: android

Are there any libraries available that allow Android applications to transcode videos to different formats? If libraries are not available, are there any applications that can be invoked through intents that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's ffmpeg, which is excellent but non trivial to get working on Android.  It has been done, though.  Consult this thread:  [FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)