# Convert Video to 3GP format

Tags: android, video

I want to convert my video .mp4 or .wav video to .3gp format. I had searched but nothing found useful. I will keep on searching but in parallel i want some hint/help to initiate task.

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017093/upload-video-from-android-to-server) but not useful for me..
also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314375/android-compress-video-before-upload-to-server/20898019#20898019) and [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950610/video-compression-on-android-using-new-mediacodec-library)

How can i do this? any idea with code snippet will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks !!

Comment: Look at http://jcodec.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have compressed the video size of 3.53MB to 128KB by using [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html?m=1)

Comment: How much time does it take in compression?