# Can we compress video and audio files in android before sending to server

Tags: android, video-compression

Iam trying to upload video and audio files from my app on android to backend using api.
But before sending want to compress them to reduce size, how can we make it?

Thanks

Comment: It is answered in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314375/android-compress-video-before-upload-to-server Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can . You can use ffmpeg library for that . For more info visit [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)