# how to play DivX videos in Android?

Tags: android

*Already asked this question, but didn't get a response, so I'm asking it again. please bear with me. :)*

How can I play DivX and other non-standard format videos ( flv, mov, etc. ) in my android app?

The only library I found was Vitamio, it does play those files, but only if the user installs an additional plugin Vitamio plugin.

Is there any way around this? either using some other library or somehow including that plugin in my app?

Thansk!

Comment: Some of these formats are proprietary, which means you need to pay for a licence, however you might want to look into VLC, it's open source and can play darn near everything.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG is what you need. [Rock Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified.lite) uses FFMpeg to play the video. Here's the [source code](http://www.rockplayer.com/tech_en.html)

Comment: looks like it's something in C++, right? are there any java ports?

Comment: Yes it's C, we can compile the library by using Android NDK, then it will produce a .so file. In order to execute the so file, u will need java jni.

Comment: This has been discussed a lot in stackoverflow. Take a look at this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)