# How to run ffmpeg from command line in android

Tags: android, command-line, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg using command line.I have saved ffmpeg.so in files directory in the project.But i am getting exception while doing so.This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Process p;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files/ffmpeg",null, new File("/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files"));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception"+e);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the exception:

```
09-16 16:21:24.992: I/System.out(2103): exceptionjava.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Commands: [/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files/ffmpeg] Working Directory: /data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files Environment: null
```

Please tell me what kind of mistake i am doing.Thanks.

Comment: Try the command with "-r" parameter for both input images and output video, for example,

ffmpeg -r 24 -i example.%d.png -vcodec mjpeg -samq -r 24 -y example.mpeg

Answer (score 14):

So firstly, you cannot directly execute a `shared object` file. You need to build a ffmpeg executable that can be run using `/system/bin`

Kindly take this as reference [FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

After you are able to get it compiled, you can but the executable in your assets folder of the APK and extract it to `/data/data/<your package>/` (ensure a chmod 755 too!)

Once that's done, you can run the executable by using building a command line string and passing it to `ProcessBuilder` instead of using the Runtime.exec()

Comment: hai Royston,ffmpeg library is not buliding in the windows os 32 bit please help me how to do that ?

Comment: Hello, i have never tried building it on Windows :)

Comment: @RoystonPinto i want to play the video in android, should i make a videoview in my xml. Please guide me with play command

Answer (score 2):

The exception mentions the 'environment' is null...

maybe instead of 'exec', try using processbuilder as in the below sample of server-side code running ffmpeg wrapped in a shellscript(pars_submit)... note builder.environment

```
        public String getFfmpeg(@QueryParam("infil1") String infil1, 
                @QueryParam("infil2") String infil2, @QueryParam("otfil") String otfil,
                @QueryParam("t") String time) {         
        String outfil = "dummy.mp4";

          List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            command.add("vendor/bin/pars_submit");

            command.add(infil1);     

            command.add(infil2);
            command.add(otfil);
            command.add(time);

System.out.println("Starting process " +command.toString());
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();
//          for(Entry<String, String> entry : environ.entrySet()){
    //          System.out.println("ENV " +entry.getKey() + " " +entry.getValue());
      //      }
//          builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = null;
            try {
                process = builder.start();

            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
              //System.out.println(line);
                outfil=line;
            }

//          int exitVal = process.waitFor();
 //           System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            finally {
                  if (process != null) {
                    process.destroy();
                    process = null;
                  }


                }           


            return outfil;


                }
```

IMO - android-ffmpeg is going to be more reliable using a full JNI interface and wrapper for the call to ffmpeg.main(). Look at all the git projects... search on 'android-ffmpeg' and look how they invoke ffmpeg. CLI is not used.

pars_submit

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
uri=$1
filnam="${uri##*/}"
uri2=$2
filnam2="${uri2##*/}"
otfil=$3
time=$4
curl -#LO  $uri
curl -#LO  $uri2
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "$filnam" -i "$filnam2" -t "$time" -r 1/2 -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -bt 50k  -an -f mp4 -strict -2 -passlogfile mydummy /dev/null
# echo "ffmpegP1 Exit status" $?
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "$filnam" -i "$filnam2" -t "$time" -r 1/2 -pass 2 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 200k -bt 50k  -f mp4 -strict -2 -passlogfile mydummy -ar 44100 "$otfil" 
# echo "ffmpegp2 Exit status" $?
# last test
json=$(curl  -X POST  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 3KxPB" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: kVl5Z0CX"  -H "Content-Type: video/mp4"  --data-binary @"$otfil" https://api.parse.com/1/files/"$otfil")
# echo "parse POST Exit status" $?
echo $json
```

Comment: Yes it works but it takes alot of time on br.readLine().. any suggestion?

Comment: Phone is not great for fast transcoding. For speed you nerd a server.