# build an encoder on android(FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I need to build an encoder on android. Trying to encode the video stream captured by camera to `h.264`.
I've got the `libffmpeg.so` file, but I don't know how to use it.

I'm new on this. Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: In `AOSP` distribution, there is already an inbuilt H.264 Encoder. Can't you make use of the same? Are you specifically looking for `FFMPEG` based encoder or any encoder?

Comment: Thank you, Ganesh. Actually I need to design a specified h.264 encoder. I'll change some details of the encoder. I think it is easier to modify the ffmpeg than the inbuilt encoder. I'm not sure about this. Am I right? Thanks again.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to customize the encoder if you require some specific inputs. I will try to answer your query based on this input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `FFMPEG` libraries on Android, you would have to integrate the same as `OMX` components.

For `ffmpeg` compilation and `OMX` generation, you could refer to this link: [FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

Once you have the `OMX` component ready, you will have to integrate the same into Android, by including the same in `media_codecs.xml`. If you desire to invoke your specific encoder always, please do ensure that your codec is the first codec registered in the list.

For the encoder, you will to have consider a couple of important points.

**One,** if you wish to optimize your system, then you may want to avoid copying of frames from the source (camera, surface or some other source) to the input port of your `OMX` encoder component. Hence, your codec will have to support passing of buffers through metadata (Reference: http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/StagefrightRecorder.cpp#1413). If you require more information on this topic, please raise a separate question.

**Two,** The encoder will have to support standard `OMX` indices and some new indices. For example, for `Miracast`, a new index `prependSPSPPStoIDRFrames` is introduced, which is supported through `getExtensionIndex`. For reference, you could refer to http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#891 .

In addition to the aforementioned index, the encoder will also get a new request to `enableGraphicBuffers` with a `FALSE` boolean value. The **most important** point for these 2 indices is to ensure that the `OMX` component doesn't fail when these 2 indices are invoked.

With these modifications, you should be able to integrate your encoder into `Stagefright` framework.