# Conversion of WMA audio file to MP3 audio file

Tags: android

I have a link of a audio file which I am playing by Adnroid MediaPlayer but the audio file is in the format of WMA and mediaplayer can't play a WMA file.

Now I need to know that is there any way so that I can play that audio file. I have searched for this problem and got few result which are suggesting to use ffmpeg for conversion but I haven't get any particular solution.

So if anybody has any solution for this problem then please tell me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the file from a computer, you can download FormatFactory at http://download.cnet.com/FormatFactory/3000-2194_4-10968547.html and do a simple file conversion with that program. If not, could you please clarify if you want to convert the file locally on your Android device or if you want the file to be converted and saved on the server that particular URL points to/