# Android video conversion

Tags: android, mobile, ffmpeg, converters, azure-mobile-services

I am a student who is doing his bachelors degree thesis. I need to implement a mobile application to convert video files from one format to another and also using a mobile service to do the same thing and compare how long did it take to perform the same tests but with different approaches.

After doing some research on how to implement the conversion on the mobile application I have only found FFMpeg. I would like to know if any of you guys have  in mind like other video converting API`s for android or something that i should consider before submitting my proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think FFmpeg is the correct way, I don't know other APIs.

There are many posts about how to implement FFmpeg on Android [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android/4820282#4820282)