# Convert Video File from SD Card to audio

Tags: android

IS there any library in android to convert video file present in SD card to audio? I am showing the list of videos present in SD card in my application and want to convert it in audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can check out [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-grabbing) for video and audio grabbing.

Comment: I was reading the link, but its hard to understand. Where to get the jar for it and which functions to use for my purpose?

Comment: You should ask that in another question.

Comment: Can you provide the answer here? I will mark correct if it works(and edit my question too).

Comment: Complicated process, i can only point you in the right direction. The coding i have to leave to you. Go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android and here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android

Comment: A simple google search of 'FFmpeg android' will yeild many results.