# Android - Video from images

Tags: android, image, video

Well, after two weeks of searching for this, I give up.
I've searched everywhere for a Java/android library to put together images and make a simple video. No luck.

I found jcodec, a promising library, but I just couldn't make it compile on eclipse. The android example given by them is throwing me errors.
Has anyone in the world accomplished this task? Is it even possible? I'm willing to pay if someone's got it.
Thank you guys in advance.
José-

Comment: anybody? really? Is it really impossible?

Comment: Have you tried with gif libraries?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do and what are you looking for? Have you looked into FFMPEG for Android? I'm currently looking into this myself, but take a look at this:
[FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

Comment: There's also jcodec which I just recently discovered. It's much easier to integrate if that's what you're looking for