# Play different sound in each ear on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, byte, stereo-3d

If I've set up two `byte` arrays to play as audio from within an Android app, is there a way I can play one in each ear simultaneously? Would there be a way to set each sound to one side or to set the balance for each one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808214/794088 might help

Comment: @petey that doesn't really tell me how to set balance/offset as far as sides/ears are concerned.

Comment: you can play two sounds at the same time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627101/playing-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-android

Comment: @petey but how do I pan/set the balance for each side?

Comment: You haven't really said anything about which API you plan on using. `MediaPlayer` has a `setVolume` method that takes two arguments, `leftVolume` and `rightVolume`.

Comment: @Michael any way to play a `byte[]` array directly through a MediaPlayer instead of reading a file?