# How to apply video filtering in android?

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am working on app like instagram where i have to apply filters on already created video and stored it in SDCard. I have searched a lot but at the end of day i find one library named FFMPEG but didn't get any help. I am newbie in video filtering. and I have setup NDK but don't know how to use this library.Is there any other way of applying filters on video and create a new video?

[image]

Comment: Another way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: @Prince, did you get your answer? i want to apply effect on video but i don't find any solution. i find one solution to show user with https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects and then send to server my effect. i want to know did you find any better solution to do this?

Comment: I have achived these by using ffmpeg in android. I will share you some code by end of the day.

Comment: @Prince Exactly i want too.. have you got it code?

Comment: @MayankSugandhi Yes i have resolved it by using ffmpeg in android. I will share code.

Comment: @Prince :- when will you upload the code , because its urgent for me.. its humble request.. :)

Comment: @Hardyk Joshi pls upload the code .

Comment: Can you please upload the code?

Comment: Yes i will. You can see i have developed this so many days ago. I need to created one demo and will upload source code with description. Thanks!

Comment: I release ExoPlayerFilter.<br>
This library uses OpenGL Shaders to apply effects on EXOPlayer video at Runtime. Please try it.<br>
https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/ExoPlayerFilter

Comment: How do you created that bitmap images according to each filter ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have a problem with configuring FFmpeg with Android [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) popular question has a good explanation on it. Apart from that to apply colour effects to a video you need to know the properties of a video that need to be changed.

[Here](http://designpieces.com/2014/09/instagram-filters-css3-effects/) you can find some of the filters that can be used with there property values. You can use those values with FFmpeg. When converting those css values to FFmpeg context you can use a [comprehensive documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#sepiaEquivalent) provided by W3 for css. Further you can play around and create fancy filters with FFmpeg. I faced the same kind of issue and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/926617/ffmpeg-applying-effects-to-a-video) I have explained the solution for some of it. Applying this kind of change to a video needs a re-encoding and therefore this process will take significant time compared to applying same effect to an image. So bare it.

FFmpeg comprise of several different filters to manipulate colour levels and its related properties like brightness, saturation, etc. You can find those different filters on [FFmpeg doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters). Always try to follow-up the documentation as most of the time they provide solutions for our problems.

Hope this helps!