# How to replace audio of a video in Android

Tags: android, audio, video, mp3, mp4

I'm trying to replace the audio of a video in Android.
I think to solutions like mute the video and put on it an audio track, but
that not works very well if you want to save the video with the track on.
Is there a way to replace the sound part of a video to make it savable?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are easier solutions, but it seems to be possible to use ffmpeg on android ([FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android][This]) might get you going at installing it). You can then strip the audio (if you have set an audiosource while recording), and add other audio to your video. You can find many example ffmpeg-commands on how to remove from and add audio to your video.

Comment: I saw some documentation, it seems I have to use C#, but I would use only java :(