# How to install ffmpeg in android studio for OSx?

Tags: macos, android-studio, ffmpeg

I need to use ffmpeg for my android project. But I couldn't find any relevant articles for this. Can anyone guide me to integrate ndk in my android studio for mac OSx.

Comment: What problem you faced while integrating?

Comment: I don't know where to start. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFMPEG on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

Comment: The above answer is outdated. In Android Studio, there is an inbuilt integration of NDK. So, I am confused how to do it in Android Studio.