# Is their any way to split video into multiple segment using ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, trim

I want to trim video into 30 seconds multiple segments in android studio.I have used the following command to trim video into 30 seconds but this is not the way i want,its just trimming video into 30 sec.Is there any FFmpeg command available to split video into multiple segments in android studio of specific duration like 30 secs?

Comment: you forgot to add the command you use here!

Comment: command = new String[]{"-ss", "" + starttime, "-y", "-i", original_path, "-t", "" +30 , "-s", "320x240", "-r", "15", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", dest.getAbsolutePath()}; 
using this command only just trim rather than split video.

Comment: i want to split video in multiple segments like 0-30,31-60,61-90 sec and so on.

Comment: if you edit your question and add this to it that will help you to get better answers :). also if you provide the code that you use to run this command, it would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this linux command in android:

```
ffmpeg -i source-file.foo -ss 0 -t 30 first-30-sec.m4v
ffmpeg -i source-file.foo -ss 30 -t 60 first-30-sec.m4v
...
```

with this you extract two parts one from second 0 to 30, and the other from 30 to 60.
you can modify it as your need, like put it in a for or change the start and end seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i [source-file-address] -ss [start second] -t [end second] [output-file-name]
```

Comment: I already done this thing but this is not break automatically split into 30 sec i want to create auto segment into 30 sec each with out take too much longer time. is their any way?

Comment: how about this command: ffmpeg -i in.wav -f segment -segment_time 5 -c copy frame-%d.wav

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android