# Convert mp4 to mp3 in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

If I understand correctly you can't use ffmpeg on android.

How can I convert either mp4 or webm to mp3 in Xamarin.Android on Android 10 and higher without using ffmpeg or any external servers?

Comment: Last I checked mp3 is audio only, is that what you want? Probably should clarify what exactly you want. Also, post what you have tried.

Comment: You [can use ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) on Android

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, I just want to extract the audio. For things I have tried, there's not much because I wasn't able to find anything useful on the internet. Mostly old posts that are long deprecated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there indeed is FFmpeg for Android.

For anyone in the same situation:
GitHub: https://github.com/Laerdal/Laerdal.FFmpeg.Android
NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Laerdal.FFmpeg.Android.Full/
On GitHub there are also links to Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.IOS and non-full builds.

Usage:
After adding package add to top of the file:
`using Laerdal.FFmpeg.Android;`
Then: `FFmpeg.Execute(string comand)`

It essentially works the same as FFmpeg in CLI.
`FFmpeg.Execute($"-i {source_file} {output_path}/filename.mp3");`
Would be same as `ffmpeg -i input_file output_file` in CLI.

Code example of converting any file type to .mp3 and handling status codes (works for .webm and .mp4, tested on Android 10):

```
int status = FFmpeg.Execute($"-i {source_file} {new_path}/filename.mp3");
if(status == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg failed with status code {status}");
}
```

If you have other questions about FFmpeg please refer to FFmpeg Documentation https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html