# How to create mp4 file from bitmap arraylist in Android

Tags: android

I want to record a mp4 file from bitmap arraylist.
My code:

```
File directory = intiFilePath();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+"/test.mp4"));
int maxBufferSize = 256 * 1024;// 256KB
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
for (Bitmap n : bmpList) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    n.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bs);
    bytesAvailable = in.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        out.flush();
        bytesAvailable = in.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
    in.close();
}
out.close();
```

But the mp4 file cannot play (the file is exist).
Anyone can help me what's wrong.

Comment: You append multiple jpg images to each other and expect this to become a playable video?

Comment: take a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5669446/3326331)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't. Try use OpenCv lib