# Android: Does Jcodec support Arraylist of Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap, jcodec

I've been searching for a possible way to convert my Bitmap (Not in drawable, I'm using canvas bitmap) into a video format. And I've found the [Jcodec](http://jcodec.org). I don't know if it support an arraylist of bitmap. And the website doesn't give any clear Instructions on how to use it in my project. I searched a lot on how to use it, but I can't find anything besides a snippets of codes, wherein I don't know if that is Jcodec or not. The sample code provided doesn't work either. If you have a simple working code on how to use it, please paste it here. What I want know is how can I make the Bitmaps I saved in arraylist.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688993/encode-a-series-of-images-into-a-video

Comment: Thank for the reply, Do I have to follow the accepted answer?

Comment: If the answer in satisfying your requirements then you can follow the answer

Comment: I think I'll stick to the Jcodec: It sounds promising to me, and I don't have any idea what the accepted answer is all about. If Jcodec doesn't give what I want, then I'll reconsider it. Thanks again

Comment: you can give thanks by providing up vote to comment