# How to view a selected images into video format in android

Tags: android, animation, image-processing, video

I am selecting a list of images from my SD card and the selected images as to view in a video format for the user. I don't know what to do is any idea or link to refer. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

@Harini- please follow up [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images) or you can try below `code`

```
        try {
File file = this.getFullPath("", "video.mp4");
SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(file);

// only 5 frames in total
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    // getting bitmap from drawable path
    int bitmapResId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("image" + i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    Bitmap bitmap = this.getBitmapFromResources(this.getResources(), bitmapResId);
    encoder.encodeNativeFrame(this.pictureFromBitmap(bitmap));
}
encoder.finish();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

 // get full SD path
File getFullPath(String filePatho, String fileName) {
File extBaseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (filePatho == null || filePatho.length() == 0 || filePatho.charAt(0) != '/') filePatho = "/" + filePatho;
makeDirectory(filePatho);
File file = new File(extBaseDir.getAbsoluteFile() + filePatho);
return new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName); // file;
}

// convert from Bitmap to Picture (jcodec native structure)
public Picture pictureFromBitmap(Bitmap src) {
Picture dst = Picture.create((int) src.getWidth(), (int) src.getHeight(), ColorSpace.RGB);
pictureFromBitmap(src, dst);
return dst;
}

public void pictureFromBitmap(Bitmap src, Picture dst) {
int[] dstData = dst.getPlaneData(0);
int[] packed = new int[src.getWidth() * src.getHeight()];

src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.getWidth(), 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());

for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++, srcOff++, dstOff += 3) {
        int rgb = packed[srcOff];
        dstData[dstOff] = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
        dstData[dstOff + 1] = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
        dstData[dstOff + 2] = rgb & 0xff;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Can you tell me how to use this, I mean where to implement this code.

Answer (score 1):

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/image-slideshow-using-viewflipper-in-android/

Hope this may help you,Or you can search for image slider in android to create image slide show

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but instead of using the slide show i can use the animation to view the images but the problem is, the taken animation will not be in the video form like mp4 format .For that what can i do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688993/encode-a-series-of-images-into-a-video